# How do I prevent the shadows of two stacked UIViews from doubling up and becoming thicker? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, shadow

I have two cards (UIViews) that are stacked directly on top of each other. Both cards have shadows applied to them using the following styling:

```
static func styleCardView(_ cardStyle: UIView) {
    cardStyle.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    cardStyle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.75)
    cardStyle.layer.shadowRadius = 1.7
    cardStyle.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cardStyle.layer.cornerRadius = 12 
}
```

After I drag the top card off the screen (UIPanGesture), the card setup resets so they are again stacked in the center as you can see in the gif below:

[Shadow issue gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZgMI.gif)

I am trying to remove any changes in the shadow thickness when the top card moves and when it resets to the center.

The issue is that the shadow of the starting point (both cards stacked) is too thick because both card shadows are stacking on top of one another. Then when the top card pans off the screen, only the shadow of the bottom card is visible. However, when the top card resets to the middle, the shadow thickness changes and the resetting of the card is obvious.

Is there any way to set a max shadow thickness that is visible or to prevent the shadows from stacking?

Comment: One thing you could do it animate the shadow opacity of the top card, so that it is 0 when they are stacked, and 1 when the top card is moved.

Comment: @Rengers - Thank you. I used something like this as a workaround:  
`if (Double(abs(xFromCenter)) + Double(abs(yFromCenter))) > 0 {  
 styleCardView(cardView)  
} else {  
styleCardViewNoShadow(cardView)  
}`  
  
It is working for now but I was hoping there would be a simpler way of doing this.